# Specify width of a column of h:panelGrid

Tags: html, css, jsf

Previously is used `<table>` tags in `JSF` forms. I notice that it is better to use `panelGrid` tag instead of it, since it is easier to use and simpler.

Previously, I used an extra `<td>` for `<h:message >` tag and give it's width to `300` to prevent form moving to left when messages appears.

Now, I'm using `width` attribute of `<h:panelGrid>` tag , but it is not my desire perform.

When any error message appears, the whole form moves left and then messages appear in front of each `input text`s .

I used `width` attribute of `message` tag, but it not worked good.

Should I have to back to use `<table>` instead of `<h:panedGrid>` ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet gg</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <center>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="400">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Username:"/>
                    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" required="true">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="30" minimum="3"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="username" />
                    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="home"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </center>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag was deprecated a long time ago. Insist upon using CSS instead `margin: 0 auto;`, `margin-left: auto;`, `margin-right: auto;`.

Comment: @Tiny I create this settings in css file with name `.makeCenter` and added it by class attribute to `form` tag like this: `<h:form id="loginForm" class="makeCenter">` , But not worked!

Comment: `.makeCenter{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}`

Comment: Those in my previous comment were just some of listings. They were not supposed to work directly. "*`auto` is replaced by some suitable value, e.g. it can be used for centering of blocks. `div { width:50%;  margin:0 auto; }` centers the div container horizontally.*" [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal behavior because the `width` attribute of the `h:panelGrid` is for the entire table and not for a particular column, you can check that in it's [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/panelGrid.html).

However, you can specify a `width` for each column by defining CSS classes for columns using the attribute `columnClasses`:

> Comma-delimited list of CSS style classes that will be applied to the
>   columns of this table. A space separated list of classes may also be
>   specified for any individual column. If the number of elements in this
>   list is less than the number of actual column children of the UIData,
>   no "class" attribute is output for each column greater than the number
>   of elements in the list. If the number of elements in the list is
>   greater than the number of actual column children of the UIData, the
>   elements at the posisiton in the list after the last column are
>   ignored.

So, in your example, assuming that you have a `style.css` file in your `css` library, you can add something like this to it:

```
  .firstColumn {
       width: 100px;
  }
  .secondColumn {
       width: 100px;
  }
  .thirdColumn { 
       width: 300px;
  }
```

After including your css file using:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
```

you can use it in your `h:panelGrid` like following:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="firstColumn,secondColumn,thirdColumn ">
    <h:outputLabel value="Username:"/>
    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" required="true">
           <f:validateLength maximum="30" minimum="3"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="username" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="home"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```